# get sca module bindings in EAR before deploying

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, websphere-8, websphere-7

I want to see all the sca bindings (imports and exports or atleast imports) associated with an EAR before deploying the EAR  to WebSphere Application Server.Is it possible to that.I can observe the bindings after deployment in WebSphere Application Server either from console or using wsadmin scripts.But is there a way to see them before deployment.

Comment: Do you have the Rational Application Developer tool?

Comment: No.Does that help?

Comment: No.Does that help?And I am new to this.Is there a difference between Websphere Integration Developer and Rational Application Developer?

Comment: Yes.  To simplify, WID should be used with "classic SCA" while RAD for "open SCA".   Which are you using?  (See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1005_fong/1005_fong.html) for some context to help understand).

Comment: I am using WID.

Comment: And you're deploying to a WebSphere Process Server / Business Process Manager (WPS or BPM) server?  Or deploying to WebSphere Application Server?

Comment: Deploying to WebSphere Application Server.

Comment: WebSphere Application Server (WAS) is not able to run the "classic SCA" modules developed with WID.  You need WPS/BPM for that.   Are you sure your application uses "classic SCA" or does it perhaps use "open SCA" (in spite of the fact that you're focused on the WID tool)?

Comment: I thought was and wps are same.I am using wps and bpm.